# Polymer-Dart 1.0.0-rc.x multiple instances of custom element causes conflict

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I built a custom element which I've added three times on my website.

```
<custom-element id="t1"></custom-element>
<custom-element id="t2"></custom-element>
<custom-element id="t3"></custom-element>
```

For some reasons, when I click something in the second or third element, the action is performed on the first one. E.g. I add a new DIV inside my custom element on an onClick event but the DIV is not added to the parent element, it's added to another instance. What is going on? Is this because Polymer dosent use shadow DOMs any longer? At least for me it seems like it's not using shadow DOMs anymore. Or is this Polymer-Dart related?

Comment: Can you add a code example/repro?

Comment: You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703490/what-are-the-different-ways-to-look-up-elements-in-polymer-1-0-polymer-dart-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
_outerCircle = querySelector('#outer-circle');
_innerCircle = querySelector('#inner-circle');
_more = querySelector('#more');
_bulletPrefab = querySelector('#bullet-prefab');
```

and

```
_outerCircle = this.querySelector('#outer-circle');
_innerCircle = this.querySelector('#inner-circle');
_more = this.querySelector('#more');
_bulletPrefab = this.querySelector('#bullet-prefab');
```

produce different results the issue is caused by your imports.
If you import `dart:html` without a prefix `document.querySelector()` is executed instead of `this.documentSelector()`.

I always import `dart:html` with a prefix to avoid this confusion.
With

```
import `dart:html` as dom;

dom.querySelector(...);
```

searches the document and

```
querySelector(...);
```

searches the children of the current element.
See [What are the different ways to look up elements in Polymer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703490) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug.

Here the code which didn't work:

```
_outerCircle = querySelector('#outer-circle');
_innerCircle = querySelector('#inner-circle');
_more = querySelector('#more');
_bulletPrefab = querySelector('#bullet-prefab');
```

and here the code which does:

```
_outerCircle = this.querySelector('#outer-circle');
_innerCircle = this.querySelector('#inner-circle');
_more = this.querySelector('#more');
_bulletPrefab = this.querySelector('#bullet-prefab');
```