# What are the different ways to look up elements in Polymer 1.0

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

There are several way in Polymer.dart 1.x to look up elements in the DOM. What are the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <body>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <app-element>
      <div id="child1"></div>
      <div id="child2"></div>
    </app-element>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
  </body>
```

```
<dom-module id='app-element'>
  <template>
    <button on-click="clickHandler">Query</button>
    <div id="shadow1"></div>
    <div id="shadow2"></div>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

The `app_element.dart` contains this import

```
import 'dart:html' as dom;
```

With shady DOM (default)

- `$["shadow1"]` (works only for statically added elements)

  - `shadow1`
- `dom.querySelectorAll('div')`

  - (a `<div hidden>` dynamically inserted by Polymer)
  - `top`
  - `shadow1`
  - `shadow2`
  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `shadow1`
  - `shadow2`
  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `shadow1`
  - `shadow2`
- `$$('div')` (returns the first element found by this selector)

  - `shadow1`

With shadow DOM (global setting to opt in)

- `$["shadow1"]` (works only for statically added elements)

  - `shadow1`
- `dom.querySelectorAll('div')`

  - (a `<div hidden>` dynamically inserted by Polymer)
  - `top`
  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `child1`
  - `child2`
- `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('div')`

  - `shadow1`
  - `shadow2`
- `$$('div')` (returns the first element found by this selector)

  - `shadow1`

Instead of `.querySelectorAll(...)` `.querySelector(...)` can be used of course but because it will always return one of the elements returned by `.querySelectorAll(...)` I didn't explicitely add these examples.

Enabling shadow DOM works the same in Polymer.dart 0.17 as explained [here for Polymer.js](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html)

Comment: Where is the shadow1 and shadow2 that are being referenced? I only see one shadow.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke Thanks for the info. It's fixed now.