# How to perform querySelectorAll on local dom in polymer dart 1.0.0.rc2?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to perform `querySelectorAll` on `local dom` of polymer element. I guess that doing simply:

```
querySelectorAll("some selector");
```

is not good idea because of all that mistic shady/shadow dom implementation details. I have tried several different ways:

```
var lst = Polymer.dom(root).querySelectorAll(".qtest");
```

gives wrapper around js array:

[image]

```
var lst2 = querySelectorAll(".qtest");
```

gives implementation of `ElementList`:

[image]

```
var lst3 = convertToDart(Polymer.dom(root).querySelectorAll(".qtest"));
```

is just simple `List` of elements:

[image]

In short: what's the proper way of calling `querySelectorAll()` that returns `ElementList` from `local dom`?

Comment: I don't really know if this would work in dart, but have you tried using `this.querySelectorAll()`? As far as I can tell that returns a Node List and that may be what you want (here's a quick [example](http://jsbin.com/sakifexidi/edit?html,output))

Comment: As I believe there is no difference between calling `this.method()` and `method()` in Dart.

Answer (score 2):

```
Polymer.dom(root).querySelectorAll('some selector');
```

Using this Polymer API ensures that you get what you want even when shady DOM or shadow DOM polyfills are used.

See also [What are the different ways to look up elements in Polymer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703490/what-are-the-different-ways-to-look-up-elements-in-polymer-1-0/32703491#32703491)

Comment: `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll()` returns elements in `light dom` but I need to query `local dom`. Of course I can change `this` to `root` but there is also other problem: returned list is not of the type `ElementList` (for example I can use `querySelectorAll().onClick` but there is no such thing as `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('').onClick`).

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up local and light DOM.  That's right, that's a limitation of this API. It's not possible to create an ElementList in JS. A workaround would be `.forEach((e) => e.onClick)`

Comment: Thank you. So it appears that I need to create my own implementation of `ElementsList` because some of exisitng pub packages (like [dnd](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dnd)) uses members of `ElementList` class.

Comment: Enabling shadow DOM could help https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html I assume with shadow DOM the normal browser API might work (like in the previous Dart Polymer version but) I didn't have a closer look yet. See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html