# What are the different ways to access a static attribute in polymer-dart 1.0.rc

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Given the following elements

## .dart

```
@PolymerRegister('x-custom')
class XCustom extends PolymerElement {
  XCustom.created() : super.created();

  static const hostAttributes = const {
    'string-attribute': 'Value',
    'boolean-attribute': true,
    'tabindex': 0,
  };
}
```

that result dynamically in the

## .html

```
<x-custom string-attribute="Value" boolean-attribute tabindex="0">
</x-custom>
```

What are the different ways to access the statically set hostAttributes in another .html and .dart file where x-custom is a child?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Imperatively if you get a reference of the element by one of the ways explained in [What are the different ways to look up elements in Polymer 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703490/what-are-the-different-ways-to-look-up-elements-in-polymer-1-0) you can do

```
var xCustom = ...;
print(xCustom.attributes['string-attribute']);
xCustom.attributes['string-attribute'] = 'otherValue';
```

or declaratively

```
<dom-module id="some-element">
  <template>
    <x-custom 
      string-attribute="{{someStringProperty}}">
    </x-custom>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

(not tested)